# Prove this equality

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$\sqrt[3]{2+11i}+\sqrt[3]{2-11i}=4$$

This is how I did it:

$$\sqrt[3]{2+11i}+\sqrt[3]{2-11i}=4 \;\;\; |^{3}$$

$$2+11i+3\sqrt[3]{(2+11i)^2(2-11i)}+3\sqrt[3]{(2+11i)(2-11i)^2}+2-11i=64$$

$$4+3\sqrt[3]{(2+11i)(2-11i)} \cdot (\sqrt[3]{2+11i}+\sqrt[3]{2-11i})=64$$

$$3\sqrt[3]{4+121} \cdot (\sqrt[3]{2+11i}+\sqrt[3]{2-11i})=60$$

$$15 \cdot (\sqrt[3]{2+11i}+\sqrt[3]{2-11i})=60$$

$$\sqrt[3]{2+11i}+\sqrt[3]{2-11i}=4$$

Is this correct?

Comment: I don't understand the first line in your proof. Can you explain it?

Comment: @tetori The "$|^3$" at the end just tells us that he's cubing it to get the next line.

Comment: This proof is not correct - you have proved the very thing you have *assumed* to be true (it's like saying 'let X be true then X must be true').

Comment: In order to prove the equality you have to turn the initial equality into something that is clearly true, not into the initial equality!

Comment: The easiest way to prove this is to first compute the cube root of $2+11i$ and of $2-11i$, separately. i.e. let $(a+bi)^3=2+11i$, then expand the bracket and find $a$ and $b$. Do the same for $2-11i$, then add them.

Answer (score 1):

Close. As [lemon](https://math.stackexchange.com/u/89931) pointed out, you started by assuming what was needed to be proven. This is easily fixed, however.

$$\sqrt[3]{2+11i}+\sqrt[3]{2-11i}=x \;\;\; |^{3}$$

$$2+11i+3\sqrt[3]{(2+11i)^2(2-11i)}+3\sqrt[3]{(2+11i)(2-11i)^2}+2-11i=x^3$$

$$4+3\sqrt[3]{(2+11i)(2-11i)} \cdot (\sqrt[3]{2+11i}+\sqrt[3]{2-11i})=x^3$$

$$3\sqrt[3]{4+121} \cdot (\sqrt[3]{2+11i}+\sqrt[3]{2-11i})=x^3-4$$

$$15 \cdot (\sqrt[3]{2+11i}+\sqrt[3]{2-11i})=x^3-4$$

$$15 \cdot x=x^3-4$$

$$x^3-15x-4=0$$

$$(x-4)(x^2+4x+1)=0$$

Since both $\sqrt[3]{2+11i}$ and $\sqrt[3]{2-11i}$ have positive real parts, we know that their sum must have a positive part. Both roots of $x^2+4x+1$ are negative, as can easily be checked, so we have:

$$\sqrt[3]{2+11i}+\sqrt[3]{2-11i}=4$$

I'm not sure if this is the easiest way to go, but it's the closest to what you already have.

Comment: Let $$\sqrt[3]{2+11i}+\sqrt[3]{2-11i}=y$$

$$y^3=2+11i+2-11i+3\sqrt[3]{(2+11i)(2-11i)}y=4+15y$$

Answer (score 0):

You can begin with
$$\sqrt[3]{2+11i}+\sqrt[3]{2-11i}=x$$
and find $x$.

Alternatively, let $z=2+11i$. You have to show that $\sqrt[3]z+\sqrt[3]{\bar z}=4$. Since $\sqrt[3]z$ and $\sqrt[3]{\bar z}$ are conjugate, it suffices to show that $\Re\sqrt[3] z=2$.

If you try to solve for $b$
$$(2+ib)^3=2+11i$$
you get
$$8-6b^2=2$$
and
$$12b-b^3=11$$
and both equations are satisfied if $b=1$.

Now, simply compute $(2+i)^3$ to check that $\sqrt[3]{2+11i}=2+i$.